# Cannot import HTTPAdapter from requests.adapters when importing clip_retrieval on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 Windows 10

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

As far as I checked all dependencies are installed and are within the ranges (see below), also I tried uninstall-install for the suspect problematic libs (flask, requests). I didn't use venv so far though if that could be a problem with some of the libs, flask in particular which breaks during importing) and I don't know if this particular Py version could be a problem.

On Windows, where I first tried, the error on WSL2 did not happen and manual importing flask and HTTPAdapter run, i.e.  `from flask import Flask` and `from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter` return fine.

In WSL, `>>> import requests` returns, but `from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter` is erroneous as in the  clip_retrieval error.

(On Win the final obstacle were (perhaps as far as I discovered) BLAS and OpenMP missing binaries/proper installation/connection/build ( `from . import _swigfaiss ...` ). I tried to fix it for a while, even manually copying .dlls (libblas.dll, libiomp5md.dll, liblapack.dll"), but the error didn't change, then I gave up and tried WSL.

```
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clip_retrieval
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/clip_retrieval/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .clip_back import clip_back
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/clip_retrieval/clip_back.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, make_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (/home/tosh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .adapters import UnixAdapter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPAdapter' from 'requests.adapters' (/home/tosh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/clip_retrieval/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .clip_back import clip_back
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/clip_retrieval/clip_back.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, make_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (/home/tosh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
>>>
```

```
 pip3 list
Package                  Version
------------------------ --------------------
aiohttp                  3.8.3
aiosignal                1.2.0
albumentations           1.3.0
aniso8601                9.0.1
async-timeout            4.0.2
attrs                    19.3.0
autofaiss                2.15.3
Automat                  0.8.0
blinker                  1.4
braceexpand              0.1.7
certifi                  2019.11.28
chardet                  3.0.4
charset-normalizer       2.1.1
click                    8.1.3
clip-anytorch            2.5.0
clip-retrieval           2.35.1
cloud-init               22.3.4
colorama                 0.4.3
command-not-found        0.3
configobj                5.0.6
constantly               15.1.0
cryptography             2.8
cupshelpers              1.0
cycler                   0.11.0
dataclasses              0.6
dbus-python              1.2.16
defer                    1.0.6
Distance                 0.1.3
distro                   1.4.0
distro-info              0.23ubuntu1
docker-pycreds           0.4.0
embedding-reader         1.5.0
entrypoints              0.3
ExifRead-nocycle         3.0.1
faiss-cpu                1.7.2
filelock                 3.8.0
fire                     0.4.0
Flask                    2.2.2
Flask-Cors               3.0.10
Flask-RESTful            0.3.9
fonttools                4.28.5
frozenlist               1.3.1
fsspec                   2022.1.0
ftfy                     6.1.1
gitdb                    4.0.9
GitPython                3.1.29
h5py                     3.7.0
httplib2                 0.14.0
huggingface-hub          0.10.1
hyperlink                19.0.0
idna                     2.8
imageio                  2.22.4
img2dataset              1.33.0
importlib-metadata       5.0.0
incremental              16.10.1
itsdangerous             2.1.2
Jinja2                   3.1.2
joblib                   1.2.0
jsonpatch                1.22
jsonpointer              2.0
jsonschema               3.2.0
keyring                  18.0.1
kiwisolver               1.3.2
language-selector        0.1
launchpadlib             1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient       0.14.2
lazr.uri                 1.0.3
macaroonbakery           1.3.1
MarkupSafe               2.1.1
matplotlib               3.5.1
more-itertools           4.2.0
multidict                6.0.2
multilingual-clip        1.0.10
netifaces                0.10.4
networkx                 2.8.8
nltk                     3.7
numpy                    1.22.0
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
oauthlib                 3.1.0
onnx                     1.11.0
open-clip-torch          2.3.1
opencv-python            4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless   4.6.0.66
packaging                21.3
pandas                   1.5.1
pathtools                0.1.2
pexpect                  4.6.0
Pillow                   9.0.0
pip                      20.0.2
prometheus-client        0.15.0
promise                  2.3
protobuf                 3.19.4
psutil                   5.5.1
pyarrow                  7.0.0
pyasn1                   0.4.2
pyasn1-modules           0.2.1
pybind11                 2.9.1
pycairo                  1.16.2
pycups                   1.9.73
PyGObject                3.36.0
PyHamcrest               1.9.0
PyJWT                    1.7.1
pymacaroons              0.13.0
PyNaCl                   1.3.0
pyOpenSSL                19.0.0
pyparsing                3.0.6
pyRFC3339                1.1
pyrsistent               0.15.5
pyserial                 3.4
python-apt               2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.8
python-dateutil          2.8.2
python-debian            0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz                     2022.6
PyWavelets               1.4.1
PyYAML                   5.3.1
qudida                   0.0.4
regex                    2022.10.31
requests                 2.28.1
requests-unixsocket      0.2.0
scikit-image             0.19.3
scikit-learn             1.1.3
scipy                    1.9.3
SecretStorage            2.3.1
sentence-transformers    2.2.2
sentencepiece            0.1.97
sentry-sdk               1.10.1
service-identity         18.1.0
setproctitle             1.3.2
setuptools               60.9.3
shortuuid                1.0.9
simplejson               3.16.0
six                      1.14.0
smmap                    5.0.0
sos                      4.4
ssh-import-id            5.10
systemd-python           234
termcolor                2.1.0
threadpoolctl            3.1.0
tifffile                 2022.10.10
tokenizers               0.13.2
torch                    1.13.0
torchvision              0.14.0
tqdm                     4.64.1
transformers             4.24.0
Twisted                  18.9.0
typing-extensions        4.1.1
ubuntu-advantage-tools   27.11.3
ufw                      0.36
unattended-upgrades      0.1
urllib3                  1.26.11
wadllib                  1.3.3
wandb                    0.12.21
wcwidth                  0.2.5
webdataset               0.1.103
Werkzeug                 2.2.2
wheel                    0.34.2
yarl                     1.8.1
zipp                     1.0.0
zope.interface           4.7.1
```

https://github.com/rom1504/clip-retrieval/blob/main/requirements.txt

```
img2dataset>=1.25.5,<2
clip-anytorch>=2.5.0,<3
tqdm>=4.62.3,<5
fire>=0.4.0,<0.5.0
torch>=1.7.1,<2
torchvision>=0.10.1,<2
numpy>=1.19.5,<2
faiss-cpu>=1.7.2,<2
flask>=2.0.3,<3
flask_restful>=0.3.9,<1
flask_cors>=3.0.10,<4
pandas>=1.1.5,<2
pyarrow>=6.0.1,<8
autofaiss>=2.9.6,<3
webdataset>=0.1.103,<0.2
h5py>=3.1.0,<4
prometheus-client>=0.13.1,<1
fsspec==2022.1.0
sentence-transformers>=2.2.0,<3
wandb>=0.12.10,<0.13
open-clip-torch>=2.0.0,<3.0.0
requests>=2.27.1,<3
aiohttp>=3.8.1,<4
multilingual-clip>=1.0.10,<2
```

EDIT: This was fixed on Windows by installing it with Anaconda (thanks to rom1504 for the suggestion that it should be run with venv - I tried to avoid using one). However another error is to be resolved. See in: https://github.com/rom1504/clip-retrieval/issues/204

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it and run the whole clip-retrieval notepad example locally and accessing the local tunnel Node.js server from the Internet. That's the code that had to be run from WSL or Windows:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/rom1504/clip-retrieval/blob/master/notebook/clip-retrieval-getting-started.ipynb

The import now completes.

```
>>> import clip_retrieval
>>> dir(clip_retrieval)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'clip_back', 'clip_end2end', 'clip_filter', 'clip_front', 'clip_index', 'clip_inference', 'ivf_metadata_ordering', 'load_clip']
```

**The solution:** I moved to Python 3.10 (maybe not strictly needed, IDK) and upgraded pip. Then there was another error during trying to run clip-retrieval command, during importing _pustil, "partial import", which happened to be a conflict in the installation, maybe mixing `sudo apt-get install` and `pip3 install`, `python3.10 -m pip install`, because the error trace included references to two different directories.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_linux as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux' from partially initialized module 'psutil' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psutil/__init__.py)
```

There were problems with removing and reinstalling the conflicting libraries, but manually deleting with
sudo rm -r ... of the folders with the modules psutil and then reinstalling it with pip finally resolved it. (There were two, which added to the confusion, one with .egg-info
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psutil-5.5.1
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psutil-5.5.1.egg-info

```
img2dataset --url_list=myimglist.txt --output_folder=image_folder --thread_count=4 --image_
size=256
Starting the downloading of this file
Sharding file number 1 of 1 called /mnt/z/myimglist.txt
0it [00:00, ?it/s]File sharded in 0 shards
Downloading starting now, check your bandwidth speed (with bwm-ng)your cpu (with htop), and your disk usage (with iotop)!
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

```
myimglist.txt

https://placekitten.com/200/305
https://placekitten.com/200/304
https://placekitten.com/200/303
https://placekitten.com/200/302
https://placekitten.com/150/235
https://placekitten.com/120/120
```

When calling clip-retrieval, it downloads

```
 clip-retrieval inference  --input_dataset image_folder --output_folder embedding_folder
The number of samples has been estimated to be 6
Starting the worker
dataset is 12
Starting work on task 0
100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 354M/354M [01:35<00:00, 3.72MiB/s]
/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clip/clip.py:160: FutureWarning: 'torch.onnx._patch_torch._node_getitem' is deprecated in version 1.13 and will be removed in version 1.14. Please Internally use '_node_get' in symbolic_helper instead..
  if "value" in node.attributeNames() and str(node["value"]).startswith("cuda"):
/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clip/clip.py:186: FutureWarning: 'torch.onnx._patch_torch._node_getitem' is deprecated in version 1.13 and will be removed in version 1.14. Please Internally use '_node_get' in symbolic_helper instead..
  if inputs[i].node()["value"] == 5:
warming up with batch size 256 on cpu
done warming up in 56.720762968063354s
/home/tosh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:554: UserWarning: This DataLoader will create 8 worker processes in total. Our suggested max number of worker in current system is 4, which is smaller than what this DataLoader is going to create. Please be aware that excessive worker creation might get DataLoader running slow or even freeze, lower the worker number to avoid potential slowness/freeze if necessary.
  warnings.warn(_create_warning_msg(
 sample_per_sec 1 ; sample_count 6
```

...

**Windows**

If that info would be useful for anyone, I realized I was trying to import clip_retrieval in CLI (on WSL I was doing the same initially), while the example usage from the sample notebook is to call it as a command.
img2dataset succeeds:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
Starting the downloading of this file
Sharding file number 1 of 1 called z:/list.txt
0it [00:00, ?it/s]File sharded in 1 shards
Downloading starting now, check your bandwidth speed (with bwm-ng)your cpu (with htop), and your disk usage (with iotop)!
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
1it [00:07,  7.66s/it]
worker  - success: 1.000 - failed to download: 0.000 - failed to resize: 0.000 - images per sec: 8 - count: 18
total   - success: 1.000 - failed to download: 0.000 - failed to resize: 0.000 - images per sec: 8 - count: 18
```

Calling clip-retrieval properly now returned another error: JAX requirement and it seems it has to be built from the source. So probably it may be just JAX, rather than OpenMP and BLAS, IDK yet.

```
clip-retrieval
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\lib\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import jaxlib as jaxlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jaxlib'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\clip-retrieval.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .clip_inference.main import main as clip_inference
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\clip_inference\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import main as clip_inference
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\clip_inference\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from clip_retrieval.clip_inference.distributor import PysparkDistributor, SequentialDistributor
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\clip_inference\distributor.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .worker import worker
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\clip_inference\worker.py", line 15, in <module>
    from clip_retrieval.clip_inference.mapper import ClipMapper
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\clip_retrieval\clip_inference\mapper.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 11, in <module>
    import transformers
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import dependency_versions_check
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .generic import (
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py", line 36, in <module>
    import jax.numpy as jnp
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jax\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from jax import config as _config_module
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jax\config.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jax._src.config import config
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\config.py", line 29, in <module>
    from jax._src import lib
  File "C:\Users\toshb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\lib\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(
ModuleNotFoundError: jax requires jaxlib to be installed. See https://github.com/google/jax#installation for installation instructions.
```